# SQL Server Database Project allowing unsupported functions for target platform

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dac, data-tier-applications

I have a SQL Server database project which is set to target SQL Server 2008 as its Target Platform.

[image: Image showing SQL Server 2008 is target platform]

In one of my stored procedures, I have code as follows:

```
DECLARE @yearEnd date
SET    @yearEnd = datefromparts(@reportingYear,8,31)
```

The particular stored procedure uses the datefromparts() function, which was introduced in SQL 2012.

My question is, how can I get the database project to not compile or create an error if someone uses a function which is not supported on the specified target platform?

At present, we do not find out about this problem until we deploy to a site which uses SQL 2008.

Comment: What version of SQL Server Data Tools have you got installed? I believe that the oldest you can get is for Visual Studio 2012, therefore, for SSDT this is valid.

Comment: It's the version which is installed with Visual Studio 2019.